# Print Data from Array to Viewlist Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to get data from a sqlite table to a view list, but when i try to connect to the database, i have a error:
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.add/admed.Listar}: java.lang.NullPointerException

The code of my db connector is:

```
  private static final String DB_NAME = "admed";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private Basedados basedados;

public BasedadosConect(Context context) {
    basedados = new Basedados(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

   public void open() throws SQLException 
   {
      //open database in reading/writing mode
      database = basedados.getWritableDatabase();
   } 

   public boolean isOpen(){
       if (database!=null){
           return true;
       } else{
           return false;
       }

   }

   public void close() 
   {
      if (database != null)
         database.close();
   }
```

The code of the class which i want to print data (Listar.java):

```
    BasedadosConect db;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Intent menu = getIntent();
String tipo = menu.getStringExtra("tipo");

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (tipo.equals("medicamentos")) {
    setContentView(R.layout.medicamentos);
    db.open();
    db.insertMed(1,"trolax","trolax",2);
    db.insertMed(2,"trolex","trolex",3);

    Cursor cursor = db.getAllmeds();
    String[] values = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {                       
        for (int i = 0; i <= cursor.getCount(); i++)
        {
            values[i] = cursor.getString(2);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }           
    }

    db.close();
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
      list.add(values[i]);
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    Button medicamentos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    medicamentos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent medsIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Editar.class);
            medsIntent.putExtra("tipo", "medicamentos");
            medsIntent.putExtra("accao", "Adicionar");
            startActivity(medsIntent);
        }
    });
}

Button voltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
voltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    }

});
  }

     private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
      }
    }
 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.string.app_name, menu);
    return true;
}
```

getAllmeds() code:

```
  public Cursor getAllmeds() 
       {
          return database.query("medicamentos", new String[]        {"medicamentos_desig"}, null, null, null, null, null);
       }
```

Full Log:

```
05-02 13:59:18.113: W/dalvikvm(714): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.add/admed.Listar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at admed.Listar.onCreate(Listar.java:34)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-02 13:59:18.123: E/AndroidRuntime(714):  ... 11 more
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: show us full log because you are getting java.lang.NullPointerException in your app..

Comment: make sure u are initializing `db` instance before using it

Comment: what is line number 34 in Listar.java??

Comment: already initialize it

Comment: line 34 is: db.open();

Comment: Add the code for your onCreate() method and highlight line 34

Comment: public void open() throws SQLException 
   {
      database = this.getWritableDatabase();
   }

Comment: dhawal already do that, rebelious i put all the code on the post now.

Comment: i k'no you have done that.. you want your code to run then create object of BasedadosConect. its give you error because you are call open without create object of BasedadosConect class..

Comment: Oh, i get it now. Very Very thanks Dhawal!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling non static method of another class. So, you need to initialize the class object before calling the member function of that class. Object declaration alone not enough.

Insert this line before db.open(); in onCreate() of Listar.Java.

```
db = new BasedadosConect(this);
```